# Pecorrer XML com php

Tags: php

Colegas.

Tenho o seguinte XML.

```
<gabarito>
   <avaliacao tipo="Prova" codigo="01" segmento="Ensino Médio" serie="Pré-Vestibular" questoes="20">
      <disciplina nome="Matemática">
         <questao numero="1" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>C</resposta>
         </questao>
         <questao numero="2" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>D</resposta>
         </questao>
         <questao numero="3" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>A</resposta>
         </questao>
      </disciplina>

      <disciplina nome="Física">
         <questao numero="1" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>C</resposta>
         </questao>
         <questao numero="2" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>D</resposta>
         </questao>
         <questao numero="3" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>A</resposta>
         </questao>
      </disciplina>
   </avaliacao>
</gabarito>
```

Como eu faria pra pegar a resposta? Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($arquivoXML);
 foreach($xml as $notasGabarito){  
  $resXML = $xml->avaliacao->disciplina->questao->resposta;
  echo "Res => " .$resXML."<br>";
 } 
}
```

Só que ele está me retornando apenas o primeiro C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você esta pegando o index direto, pela forma que você montou o xml terá que percorrer questão a questão para pegar a resposta.

Detalhe, não sei se você colocou errado o  xml mas ele apresenta alguns erros sintáticos.

**Exemplo:**

Arquivo foo.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gabarito>
   <avaliacao tipo="Prova" codigo="01" segmento="Ensino Médio" serie="Pré-Vestibular" questoes="20">
      <disciplina nome="Matemática">
         <questao numero="1" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>C</resposta>
         </questao>
         <questao numero="2" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>D</resposta>
         </questao>
         <questao numero="3" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>A</resposta>
         </questao>
      </disciplina>
   </avaliacao>
</gabarito>
```

Lendo o arquivo foo.xml

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('foo.xml');
$questoes = count($xml->avaliacao->disciplina->questao);
for ($i = 0; $i < $questoes; $i++):
   print($xml->avaliacao->disciplina->questao[$i]->resposta);
endfor;
```

Saida:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => C ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => D ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => A )
```

Para ler atributos do xml:

```
$disciplina= count($xml->avaliacao->disciplina);
for ($i = 0; $i < $disciplina; $i++):
   print_r($xml->avaliacao->disciplina[$i]->attributes()['nome']);
endfor;
```

Comment: Perfeito Gabriel, funcionou... agora e se for no caso do gabarito? Estou querendo pegar o nome das disciplinas, que são mais de uma, porém também não estou conseguindo. Como eu faria nesse caso?

Comment: @Jose.Marcos é bem simples, faz um count do gabarito, se tiver 50 gabaritos, você faz um for igual ao exemplo acima apenas iterando com a variavel $i nele, vai dando um print pra debugar

Comment: certo... fiz conforme vc falou, mas retorna somente o nome da primeira disciplina, ou seja, Matemática... como eu faria para pegar também a Física?