# Como pegar dados xml com php?

Tags: php, xml

Estou tentando integrar meu sistema com a transportadora jadlog mas não consigo pegar os dados do xml com php.

[url de retorno da jadlog](http://www.jadlog.com.br:8080/JadlogEdiWs/services/ValorFreteBean?method=valorar&vModalidade=5&Password=C2o0E1m3&vSeguro=N&vVlDec=100,00&vVlColeta=10,00&vCepOrig=89062080&vCepDest=89062080&vPeso=30,30&vFrap=N&vEntrega=D&vCnpj=17977285000118)

Resultado:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
    <valorarResponse xmlns="">
        <ns1:valorarReturn xmlns:ns1="http://jadlogEdiws">
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
            <string xmlns="http://www.jadlog.com.br/JadlogEdiWs/services">
                <Jadlog_Valor_Frete>
                    <versao>1.0</versao>
                    <Retorno>114,11</Retorno>
                    <Mensagem>Valor do Frete</Mensagem>
                </Jadlog_Valor_Frete>
            </string>
        </ns1:valorarReturn>
    </valorarResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Tentei pegar os dados da seguinte maneira:

```
$retornoJadlog= simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($urlJadlog));
```

ou

```
$retornoJadlog= simplexml_load_string($urlJadlog);
```

Mas das duas maneiras o retorno é null:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (0) {
}
```

Comment: Amigão, o retorno acima não é null. Ele está retornando o `SimpleXmlElement`. É um objeto contendo as informações.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Pecorrer XML com php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124494/pecorrer-xml-com-php)

Comment: Como faço pra acessar os dados? pois usando var_dump() o retorno é o que mostrei na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vê se é isso que precisa patrão:

```html
<?php

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("http://www.jadlog.com.br:8080/JadlogEdiWs/services/ValorFreteBean?method=valorar&vModalidade=5&Password=C2o0E1m3&vSeguro=N&vVlDec=100,00&vVlColeta=10,00&vCepOrig=89062080&vCepDest=89062080&vPeso=30,30&vFrap=N&vEntrega=D&vCnpj=17977285000118");

$x = $xmlDoc->documentElement;
foreach ($x->childNodes AS $item) {
  print $item->nodeName . " = " . $item->nodeValue . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Resultado do print_r: SimpleXMLElement Object ( )

Comment: Peri...rapidão...

Comment: no aguardo.....

Comment: Tava almoçando... Agora tô legalzão.... Thô vê se consigo ajudar.....Problema é saber o que exatamente se quer pegar... Mas vai um tiro ai , vai que acerta.... Tira as crianças de perto...kkk POW, se acerto num esquece de valida e fecha a resposta...vlw ;)

Comment: Consegui ae patrão ?

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!

Comment: E como fazer com um arquivo xml em uma pasta do computador?

Comment: @UlissesGimenes `$xmlDoc->load('path/do/arquivo.xml')`

Comment: Eu queria fazer uma importação de um xml de nota fiscal eletronica para pegar os dados de nome da tranportadora e peso bruto para jogar esses dados em um recibo que eu iria gerar e fica dando erro de utf8 com utf16, tem alguma forma de resolver

Comment: Pode ser uma série de fatores, abra uma questão e coloque o código e os problemas....@UlissesGimenes